# Migrating from the Google Cloud Storage API java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have problems to update my deprecated code to new one. Following this code of Google sample works on deprecated mode but not in new; 
link below-->

[google sample](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/migrate#migration_example)

```
  package com.google.appengine.demos;

import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsFileOptions;
import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsFilename;
import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsInputChannel;
import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsOutputChannel;
import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsService;
import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Create, Write, Read, and Finalize Cloud Storage objects.
 * Access your app at: http://myapp.appspot.com/
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PortOfFilesAPIGuestbookServlet extends HttpServlet {
   public static final String BUCKETNAME = "ExampleBucketName";
   public static final String FILENAME = "ExampleFileName";

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world from java");
    GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
    GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename(BUCKETNAME, FILENAME);
    GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder()
        .mimeType("text/html")
        .acl("public-read")
        .addUserMetadata("myfield1", "my field value")
        .build();

    GcsOutputChannel writeChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(filename, options);
    // You can write to the channel using the standard Java methods.
    // Here we use a PrintWriter:
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(Channels.newWriter(writeChannel, "UTF8"));
    writer.println("The woods are lovely dark and deep.");
    writer.println("But I have promises to keep.");
    writer.flush();

    // Note that the writeChannel is Serializable, so it is possible to store it somewhere and write
    // more to the file in a separate request. To make the object as small as possible call:
    writeChannel.waitForOutstandingWrites();

    // This time we write to the channel directly
    writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap("And miles to go before I sleep.".getBytes("UTF8")));

    // If you want partial content saved in case of an exception, close the
    // GcsOutputChannel in a finally block. See the GcsOutputChannel interface
    // javadoc for more information.
    writeChannel.close();
    resp.getWriter().println("Done writing...");

    // At this point, the file is visible to anybody on the Internet through Cloud Storage as:
    // (http://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKETNAME/FILENAME)

    GcsInputChannel readChannel = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
      // We can now read the file through the API:
      readChannel = gcsService.openReadChannel(filename, 0);
      // Again, different standard Java ways of reading from the channel.
      reader = new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(readChannel, "UTF8"));
      String line;
      // Prints "The woods are lovely, dark, and deep."
      // "But I have promises to keep."
      // "And miles to go before I sleep."
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        resp.getWriter().println("READ:" + line);
      }
    } finally {
      if (reader != null) { reader.close(); }
    }
  }
}
```

I add the permissions, add the libraries... but always I see this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/googleapis/services/json/AbstractGoogleJsonClient$Builder
```

I need add something else? some Oauth key? Somebody have a full example with libraries that I need add?

Your help will be appreciated

Thanks

Christian

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the Google API client libs, you can download them [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#google-api-client-appengine)

Using those services with OAuth for GAE should be pretty straightforward [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Google_App_Engine_identity) are some examples.

Comment: I have already Google Api client libs , same as you attached (including all of these). With appengine-gcs-client-0.3.jar works but from version 0.3.8 not. It makes sense? I would like have last version or one of them  because is the best, I think so. About OAuth is necessary add some extra code like you attached? I say because I add the permissions over the bucket and in theory should be enough, not? Because with version 0.3.0 works. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Are all libs in the WEB-INF/lib folder?

Comment: Well I think, I have on my lib-->appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.18.jar , appengine-api-labs.jar, appengine-api-stubs-1.7.7.jar, appengine-endpoints.jar, appengine-endpoints-deps.jar, appengine-gcs-client-0.3.jar, appengine-jsr107cache-1.9.18.jar, appengine-local-runtime-shared.jar, appengine-testing-1.8.8.jar, asm-4.0.jar, commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.3.jar, datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.3.jar, datanucleus-appengine-2.1.2.jar, datanucleus-core-3.1.3.jar ,el-api-2.2.jar, geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0.jar, geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.1.1.jar...

Comment: geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0.jar, geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.1.1.jar, geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar, google-api-client-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar, google-api-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar, google-api-client-appengine-1.19.0.jar, google-api-client-jackson2-1.19.0.jar, google-api-client-servlet-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar, google-api-services-datastore-protobuf-v1beta2-rev1-2.1.0.jar, google-api-services-drive-v2-rev162-1.20.0.jar, google-api-services-storage-v1-rev28-1.20.0.jar, google-http-client-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar, google-http-client-1.19.0.jar, google-http-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar

Comment: google-http-client-appengine-1.19.0.jar, google-http-client-jackson-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar, google-http-client-jackson-1.19.0.jar, google-http-client-jackson2-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar, google-http-client-jackson2-1.19.0.jar, google-http-client-protobuf-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar, google-oauth-client-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar, google-oauth-client-1.19.0.jar, google-oauth-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar, google-oauth-client-java6-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar, google-oauth-client-jetty-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar, google-oauth-client-servlet-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar, gson-2.1-sources.jar, guava-18.0.jar

Comment: guava-jdk5-13.0.jar, gwt-servlet.jar, httpclient-4.0.1-sources.jar, httpclient-4.0.1-tests.jar, httpcore-4.0.1.jar, httpcore-4.0.1-sources.jar, jackson-core-2.1.3-sources.jar, jcommander-1.32.jar, jdo2-api-2.3-eb-sources.jar, jdo-api-3.0.1.jar, joda-time-2.7.jar, joda-time-2.7-sources.jar, jsp-api-2.0.jar, jsr107cache-1.1.jar, jsr305-2.0.1.jar, jta-1.1.jar, junit-4.10.jar, mockito-all-1.8.4.jar, protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar, servlet-api.jar, transaction-api-1.1-sources.jar, xpp3-1.1.4c. and xpp3-1.1.4c-sources.jar. That's all. You see something some mistake? sorry for this long list... Thanks

Comment: I succeeded! it was some library... but the worst is that you need add extra libraries besides google says on your web. Really a nightmare.. Thanks for your time has been appreciated